# Using return value by a function in outside

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to implement this function that help me to use the result of select in outside but the setState function does not work. So how can I do it please?

```
selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions) {
        console.log('selecting data...')
        let command = new SelectCommand();
        let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions); //db_cmd = select * from Person for exemple

        var that = this;
        db.transaction((txn) => {
            txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [],  (tx, res) => {
                that.setState({select_res, res});
            });
        });
        return this.state.select_res;
    }
```

Comment: which module you are using for `sqlite` ?

Comment: I use [react-native-sqlite-2](https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

        let command = new SelectCommand();
        let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions);

        db.transaction((txn) => {
            txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [], (tx, res) => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
            });
        }); 
    });
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
db_cmd.selectFromTable('Agriculteur', ['*'], null).then((result) => {
  //here do what you want with the results
})
```

Comment: I am happy to hear that it helped you:D

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
    console.log('selecting data...')
    let command = new SelectCommand();
    let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions);

    let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction((txn) => {
            txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [], (tx, res) => {
                resolve(res);
            });
        });
    });
    result.then((res) => {
        return res;
    });
}
```

Comment: I used this code for calling the function: `var res = db_cmd.selectFromTable('Agriculteur', ['*'], null);
        console.log(res);` but the result is `undefind`

Comment: Also this `console.log` in `then` `result.then((res) => {
        console.log('resul: ' + res)
        return res;
    });` don't print anything

Comment: can you also replace the "txn" with "tx"?:)

Comment: The `console.log('result: ' + res)` in `then` print `result: [object Object]` :) and this result is with txn et tx

Comment: I use `console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(res))` and the result was printed but i need an json object like returned data and how can I return this value for using It outside.

Comment: can you do: console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(res))

Comment: Then I think you have to make your own array of objects (result is an array declared before db.transaction):   for(var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = res.rows.item(i)
            result[i] = { id: row['firstfield'],
                          name: row['secondfield'] (etc)
            }
         }

Comment: Yes, But just inside `then` and JSON.stringify convert it to json string, how can I return this value for using It outside :)

Comment: `selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
    console.log('selecting data...')
    let command = new SelectCommand();
    let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions);

    let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction((txn) => {
            txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [], (tx, res) => {
                resolve(res.rows);
            });
        });
    });
    result.then((res) => {
        console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(res))
        return res;
    });
}`

Comment: I think that in the "then" you can write: return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)) or in place of res use your new build array of objects:)

Comment: I use this code for calling the function :) `var res = db_cmd.selectFromTable('Agriculteur', ['*'], null).then((result) => {
            return result;
        })` I need the res var

Comment: you have to use it  like this: var res = db_cmd.selectFromTable('Agriculteur', ['*'], null).

Comment: let me try to write the promise in another way. I will come back with another answer in few minutes:)

Comment: When I'm calling the function I've used this `db_cmd.selectFromTable('Agriculteur', ['*'], null, function(res) {
            console.log('result:: '+ JSON.stringify(res));
        });` and in `then` I've used this `Callback(res)` So It's working now Thanks++ man ;) you are the boos :)

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use promises or callbacks. I am expecting that the db.transaction takes some time until gives back the results. Because the action is async, in the moment of the return, you will not have yet a result in the select_res:)

Can you try this:

```
selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
    console.log('selecting data...')
    let command = new SelectCommand();
    let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions);

    let result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction((txn) => {
            txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [], (tx, res) => {
                resolve(res);
            });
        });
    });
    result.then((res) => {
        return res;
    });
}
```

?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use It but the problem does not resolved.I will post my code in an answer

Answer (score 0):

This my solution for promises or callbacks

**Callback**

```
selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
        console.log('selecting data...')
        let command = new SelectCommand();
        let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions);

        var that = this;
        db.transaction((txn) => {
            txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [],  (tx, res) => {
                callback(res)
            });
        });
    }
```

and when I trying to use it I use

```
db_cmd.selectFromTable('Person', ['*'], null, function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
```

**Promises**

```
async selectFromTable(table_name, selected_columns, conditions, callback) {
        console.log('selecting data...')
        let command = new SelectCommand();
        let db_cmd = command.select_from_table(table_name, selected_columns, conditions);

        var result = await db.transaction(async (txn) => {
            var select_res = await txn.executeSql(db_cmd, [],  (tx, res) => {
                select_res = res;
                return select_res;
            });
            result = select_res;
            return result;
        });
        return result;
    }
```

and when I trying to use it I use

```
create_data_base = async () => {
        let db_cmd = new DB_Command();
        var res = await db_cmd.selectFromTable('Agriculteur', ['*'], null).then((x) => {
            return x;
        });
        console.log(res);
    }
```

So if I have any problem in this code pls help me.

Comment: @AndreiPislariu